# Cannot resolve symbol "VolleyApplication"

Tags: android, android-volley

cannot resolve symbol VolleyApplication while using ImageLoader

```
public void getImageFromURL() {
        showProgressDialog();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = VolleyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        // Using NetworkImageView
        networkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
        networkImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: use  volleyRequestQueue = VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        imageLoader = volleyRequestQueue.getImageLoader();

Comment: VolleyRequestQueue is not available so i used RequestQueue instead but it is also not supporting getInstance() method...